# Как вызвать одно окно из слота другого Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

q2 главное стартовое окно. У него есть кнопка QButton pushButton. При нажатии на неё должно появляться другое окно из класса online с выводом списка, который передается параметром в конструкторе q2. Видел примеры кода в интернете, делал так же, но почему-то по нажатию ничего не происходит

main.cpp

```
    #include "q2.h"
#include "online.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    stack <string> s;
    s.push("Roman");
    s.push("Marina");

    q2 w(s);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

q2.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_q2.h"
#include "ui_online.h"
#include "online.h"
#include <string>

class q2 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    q2(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    q2(stack <string> s);

public slots:

    void CreateOnline(stack <string> sta)
    {
        online* one = new online;
        one->online::showOnline(sta);
        one->QWidget::show();
    }

private:
    Ui::q2Class ui;
};
```

online.h

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "ui_online.h"
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <QListView>
using namespace std;

class online : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    online(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    void showOnline(stack <string> s);

private:
    Ui::online ui;
};
```

online.cpp

```
online::online(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

void online::showOnline(stack <string> s)
{
    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
    QStandardItem *item;

    while (!s.empty())
    {
        string g = s.top();
        s.pop();
        QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(g);
        item = new QStandardItem(qstr);
        model->appendRow(item);
    }
    ui.listView->setModel(model);
}
```

q2.cpp

```
q2::q2(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(close()));
}

q2::q2(stack <string> s)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(CreateOnline(s)));
    QObject::connect(ui.out, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас слот не подключается в конструкторе `q2::q2(stack<string>)`. Так как во-первых вы пытаететесь подключаться к `qApp`, а у него такого слота нет. Во-вторых `connect` не поддерживает ни параметры по умолчанию, ни передачу их из вне, то есть `SLOT(CreateOnline(s))` вообще ни к месту и как оно скомпилировалось не понятно:

```
q2::q2(stack <string> s)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect
    (
          ui.pushButton
        , SIGNAL(clicked())
        , qApp                   // видимо имелось в виду this
        , SLOT(CreateOnline(s))  // здесь s не передастся
    );
    QObject::connect(ui.out, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

Исправить можно с помощью подключения лямбды например:

```
q2::q2(stack <string> s)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect
    (
          ui.pushButton
        , &QPushButton::clicked
        , [this, s]() -> void // лямбда захватывает s
          {
              this->CreateOnline(s);
          }
    );
    QObject::connect(ui.out, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

Подробней про новый [способ подлючения слотов](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) (англ.)

Comment: к сожалению, он не принимает даже лямбду. Выдает c2664, не может преобразовать в const char* третий аргумент